# Use JFrog Artifactory as Terraform Data Source

Tags: artifactory, terraform

I'm desiring to pull a jar file from JFrog artifactory and use it as the source to deploy to an AWS Lambda function using Terraform. I am currently doing this by pulling from an S3 bucket using the code below:

```
data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "function-lambda-file-hash" {
  bucket = "<MYBUCKET>
  key    = "<MYKEY.sha1>"

  tags {
    Name = "${var.<MYTAG>}"
  }
}

# Create the Lambda function itself
resource "aws_lambda_function" "function-lambda" {
  function_name = "function-lambda"

  handler = "com.example.MyFunction::handleRequest"
  runtime = "java8"
  s3_bucket="<MYBUCKET>"
  s3_key="<MYKEY.jar>"
  source_code_hash = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.function-lambda-file-hash.body}"
  role = "${aws_iam_role.function-lambda-exec-role.arn}"
  timeout = 30
  memory_size = 256

  tags {
    Name = "${var.<MYTAG>}"
  }
}
```

I would like to do something identical but pulling from Artifactory, an instance that requires authentication (which it appears that the HTTP module cannot do), instead but have not been able to find any information regarding doing this. Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, how?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: You may want to follow Atlassian's [artifactory terraform provider](https://github.com/atlassian/terraform-provider-artifactory). They don't have any data sources yet but I'm sure they would accept a pull request.

Comment: Chris Slack any update on this? I am looking for similar requirement

Comment: @sahit @chris-slack Looks like they have a data source now `data "artifactory_file" "test" {}` but no documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the data source [`artifactory_file`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/jfrog/artifactory/latest/docs/data-sources/artifactory_file) to get the sha256, then base64 encode it, and pass it to the `aws_lambda_function` resource.

```
# Configure the Artifactory provider
# You may want to use SSM/SecretsManager data sources
# to configure the username and password
provider "artifactory" {
  url      = "${var.artifactory_url}/artifactory"
  username = var.artifactory_username
  password = var.artifactory_password
}

data "artifactory_file" "jar" {
  repository  = "repo-key"
  path        = "/path/to/the/artifact.jar"
  output_path = "artifact.jar"
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "default" {
  function_name = "fantastic_service_name"

  source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.artifactory_file.jar)

  # ...
}
```

Comment: Can we ignore `filename` Lambda's argument in this case?

Comment: Doesn't work using `.sha256` for artifactory_file data (no such field). Probably, we should use such statement `source_code_hash = filebase64sha256(data.artifactory_file.jar)`

Comment: @YevhenTkachenko thanks! I updated the above to reflect your suggested fix